# SQL recursive - sort and group data depending on level and its parents, then display results in JSON format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, recursive-query

I have the database with the structure and data like the following SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE folder_tree (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    level INTEGER,
    parent_id INTEGER,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES folder_tree (id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

```
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section A', 0, null, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section B', 0, null, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section B.1', 1, 2, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section A.1', 1, 1, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section C', 0, null, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section B.1.1', 2, 3, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section B.1.2', 2, 3, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section B.2', 1, 2, NOW());
INSERT INTO folder_tree (name, level, parent_id, created_at) VALUES ('Section C.1', 1, 5, NOW());
```

My purpose is to sort and group data depending on level and its parent id, then show the results in JSON format. Here is the SQL query I did:

```
WITH json_agg_scope_cte AS (
  WITH scope_cte AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE sub_scopes_cte AS (
      SELECT
        s.*,
        NULL :: JSON AS sub_scopes
      FROM
        folder_tree s
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM folder_tree
          WHERE parent_id = s.id
      )

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
        s.*,
        row_to_json(ssc) AS sub_scopes
      FROM
        sub_scopes_cte ssc
        JOIN folder_tree s
          ON s.id = ssc.parent_id
    )

    SELECT
      id,
      name,
      json_agg(sub_scopes) AS sub_scopes
    FROM sub_scopes_cte ssc
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY 1, 2
  )

  SELECT
    s.*,
    sc.sub_scopes
  FROM folder_tree s
    INNER JOIN scope_cte sc
      ON s.id = sc.id
)

SELECT json_agg(json_agg_scope_cte.*) AS scopes
FROM json_agg_scope_cte
```

My expected output sequence:

```
├── A
│   └── A.1
├── B
│   ├── B.1
│   │   ├── B.1.1
│   │   └── B.1.2
│   └── B.2
└── C
    └── C.1
```

But after executing the query, the output sequence in JSON displays like the following structure:

```
├── A
│   └── A.1
├── B
│   ├── B.2
│   ├── B.1
│   │   └── B.1.1
│   └── B.1
│       └── B.1.2
└── C
    └── C.1
```

So what is wrong with the SQL above and is there another solution for it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See if this solve this problem :

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec AS (id , name ,level ,parent_id , createdat)(
SELECT id , name ,level ,parent_id , createdat 
FROM folder_tree AS a WHERE parent_id IS NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id , name , level , parent_id ,createdat 
FROM folder_tree AS b 
JOIN rec AS c ON c.id = b.parent_id 
)
SELECT * FROM rec;
```

The first query inside of WITH garantees that only rows withouth parent get called , then the union all will join the WITH rec records  to call only the rows that have the parent_id equals to the ids from the second instance of the table.

Comment: I tried to execute your solution, but the result is still not the one that I expected. It returns rows like the following query: "SELECT * FROM folder_tree ORDER BY level ASC"

What I mean, is to sort data in recursive, for example, after getting the first row (id = 1, level 0), you need to find all ids with parent_id = 1 (level 1). If exists, you return the first row, then continue to find all ids with parent_id equal to the id of row that you returned above (level 2). If not, then you return the next row and do recursive again until the end of data.

Comment: To create a level you could increase a column called 0 level , then on the union ALL query you can place c.level+1 on the columns select . Then all the records will be capable to be classified .Also add the level columns to the WITH Recursive columns usage.